# mysql direct insert from complex select

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have this MySQL SELECT:

```
SELECT t.*,
 sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'),
 STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS ARBEITSZEIT,
sum(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Projektbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'),
STR_TO_DATE(Projektende, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')))) AS Projektzeit

FROM (SELECT DriverName,
         Baustelle,
         Arbeitsbeginn,
         Arbeitsende,
        Projektbeginn,
        Projektende
  FROM (SELECT DRIVERNAME,
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', AREA, NULL)) AS 'Baustelle',
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsbeginn', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsbeginn',
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsende', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsende',
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektbeginn',
               GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PE', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektende'
        FROM geoImportRoot
        GROUP BY DRIVERNAME
       ) A CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2) n
) t
GROUP BY DriverName;
```

Is it possible to get this inserted directly into a new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a *new* table from a select statement you could use:

[`CREATE TABLE .... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html)

It is basically a `CREATE TABLE` statement with a `SELECT` statement appended.

---

If you wish to insert the `SELECT` result in an *existing* table, use instead the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) statement.